# problem with pattern of sequance

Tags: sequences-and-series

there is a sequence $a_1=1^2, a_2=3^2, a_3=6^2, ...$ I'm thinking if there is a pattern of this progression, but so far I haven't find out.

I noticed that the difference of only the square number increase by $n+1$ for eg. $3-1=2$, $6-3=3$

Answer (score 1):

Three terms are not enough to form a defensible conjecture about the intended  sequence.

However $1,3,6,10,15,\dots$ gives the **triangular numbers** $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and we are given the squares of the first three. Alternately, we are looking at $1^3$, $1^3+2^3$, $1^3+2^3+3^3$, and so on. (That gives the same sequence as the squares of the triangular numbers.)

Comment: You are welcome. Please note the **very** tentative nature of the answer, it is one among infinitely many possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer this question without more terms in the series, but the obvious pattern is
$$
a_n=(\frac{n(n+1)}2)^2= {n+1\choose 2}^2
$$

That is: they may be the "triangular numbers."

Answer (score 1):

I think about your question exactly as @Andre. There are not enough terms here we can form them as a well-defined sequence(s). Whenever you have enough terms then consult [here](http://oeis.org/).